# How to access rows of a table from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am creating a stored procedure with @dbname, @schemaname and @tablename as parameters, with the objective of count the nulls in every column of the table chosen, but i cant acess the data from a different database.

i was trying something like this

```
create or alter proc testnulls(
       @dbname     sysname = N'master', 
      @schemaname sysname = N'dbo', 
      @tablename  sysname = N'spt_values'
      )
as

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) 

select @sql = @sql + '
   sum(case when [' + c.name + '] is null then 1 else 0 end) as [' + c.name + '_NULLS]'
fROM sys.columns AS c 
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS t
ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
where t.name = @tablename
and s.name=@schemaname

set @sql = @sql + ' from '+ QUOTENAME(@dbname)+  N'.'+ QUOTENAME(@schemaname)+ N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)
select @sql
```

Comment: Please add the query that you are using? Please show us the work that you have done and the issue at which you are stuck?

Comment: When you say " I can't access the data from a different database". Are you getting an error, if so, can you share that error?  If it's isn't an error, what are you getting instead that tells you can't access the database?

Comment: i am not getting any column name or do anything with the table of a different database    @JNevill

Comment: The `sys` objects are always going to reference the *local* database, not the other database's `sys` objects. You'll need to use dynamic dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: any tip on how to do it ? @Larnu i already tried a lot of things and nothing...

Comment: It'll be a mess... ;)

Comment: You add the database name to the system table references in your first query - which must use dynamic sql just like you do in the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saying, it's not pretty; dynamic dynamic SQL never is. Not going to lie, I really don't want to explain what this is doing, it's a mess. I suggest using the `PRINT` statements I put in it to debug it if required.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.testnulls @dbname     sysname = N'master', 
                                   @schemaname sysname = N'dbo', 
                                   @tablename  sysname = N'spt_values' AS
BEGIN 

    --DECLARE @dbname     sysname = N'master', 
    --        @schemaname sysname = N'dbo', 
    --        @tablename  sysname = N'spt_values';

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @DSQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = N'SET @DSQL = N''SELECT '' + STUFF((SELECT N'', COUNT('' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'') AS '' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(c.[name],N''_NULL''))
                                                   FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.schemas s
                                                         JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.all_objects o ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
                                                         JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
                                                   WHERE s.[name] = @schemaname
                                                     AND o.[name] = @tablename
                                                   FOR XML PATH(N''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''nvarchar(MAX)''),1,2,N'''') + 
                             N''FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@schemaname) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + N';''
               EXEC sys.sp_executesql @DSQL, N''@schemaname sysname, @tablename sysname'', @schemaname, @tablename;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@schemaname sysname, @tablename sysname, @DSQL nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @schemaname, @tablename, @DSQL OUT;

    PRINT @DSQL;
    PRINT @SQL;
END;
```

Comment: did a few adjustments to get the sum of nulls, but now it seems not work for empty strings

Comment: If you e changed the solution i can't comment why it doesn't work anymore, @FranciscoBorges, something you did broke it. It worked for as is for me. If you've made changes then use the debugging stuff I included.